# Context deadline exceeded- goteberg api (/forms/libreoffice/convert)

Tags: docker, libreoffice, pdf-conversion, unoconv, gotenberg

I am trying to convert ms-office files to pdf using gotenberg api. For some files, i am getting unoconv PDF context deadline exceeded  with 503 status. I have increased the read, write and process timeout to 60 secs. How can i resolve this issue? What is the the maximum time take to convert the file? What is the maximum request can be handled by one gotenberg instance?

Answer (score 2):

Try increase timeout in gotenberg by passing `--api-timeout` to container start command

```
gotenberg:
  image: gotenberg/gotenberg:7
  command: gotenberg --log-level=info --api-timeout 400s
```